# Javascript current location in all browser code?

Tags: javascript, location

I want to create application to fetch the current location data using Java script.

I want to use this code in any of the browser Firefox,IE,Safari,Chrome,Opera mini along with any version.(1.x,2.x,3.x,.4.x)....

I have tried but it is running with some of the browser and with limited version.

can any body help me out to find out the solution for finding current location using java script for any browser which is compatible .....please share code snippet or any useful link...

thanks,
mishal shah

Comment: "Opera mini along with any version"? That's unlikely - support for physical location data was only added in version 4, IIRC (and it's been a *loooong* time since I've last seen a previous version of Opera Mini). Note that version 5 has been out for some time.

Comment: What do you mean by "Location"? Geographical location of the user? Location (URL) of the current page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution which abstracts from platform http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/ if you talk about geolocation.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_geolocation.html) is a better resource which includes information about both [**W3C Geolocation standard**](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html)
and **Google Gears Geolocation API**

http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_geolocation.html